# When using localization, how can we omit specific design elements from being translated?

Tags: xpages

We have a multilingual XPages application, and we are using the localization feature that comes with XPages.  There are certain design elements that we don't need (or don't want) translated.  Is there a way to omit certain XPages or custom controls from creating property files, for nothing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using XPages localization feature you can store all your translations in a single properties files for each language. This means you instead need to specify each label in your xpages that you need to translate. but the advantage is that you have only one file for each language to send for translation and you have complete control of what is translated on your site.

Your properties files is a text list with a parameter and a value like this:   save=Save

To use this you need to add your properties files as a resource bundle to your xpages and set a variable.

```
<xp:this.resources>
<xp:bundle var="translate" src="/translation.properties"></xp:bundle>
</xp:this.resources>
```

In your xpage you can get the translated value using your varible like this translate["save"]

Xpages will use the properties file associated with the html attribute HTML lang="en"> 
so if the attribute is "en" XPages will use a file called translation_en.properties if it exist, if not it will use the default translation.properties

Changing your site from the xpages localization feature to resource bundles may cause a lot of extra work initally but is well worth it in the long run. at least that is my experience.

Comment: And you are able to change the translations during runtime.

Comment: Thanks!  The problem isn't sending the information for translation.  Most of the translations can be in the Notes client from the user's perspective.  The issue is that many pages do not need any translation files (using localization or not).

Also, there are many labels, buttons and other elements, and it would take forever to redo it this way.  Instead of an alternative, I'd prefer a solution.